# Why can't I get location using CID, LAC, MCC and MNC?

Tags: android, geolocation, cellid

I get CID, MNC, MCC, LAC from this code

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
cid = cellLocation.getCid();
lac = cellLocation.getLac();
```

and I put it in here http://opencellid.org/cell/get?key=???&mcc=520&mnc=18&lac=24511&cellid=282399 and I get back error anyone can tell me what should I do?

Are there other ways to get Lat Lon Using CID, MNC, MCC, LAC on android?

Comment: Please add the error you receive.

Comment: Please click that link.

Comment: It is good to have the error here as cite or similar if the endpoint is offline or changed its API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I´m Markus, the maintainer of OpenCellID.
I guess that worldwide more than 50.000.000 base stations exist.
OpenCellID currently has 5.5 million base stations in its database.
I checked the database and found out, that the cell you are looking for is not (yet) in the OpenCellID database.

The best way to overcome this chicken-and-egg problem is if apps contribute to OpenCellID and use OpenCellID data at the same time.
OpenCellID has recently published an Android library which makes contribution to OpenCellID as well as using the OpenCellID data as easy as possible. You can find more information here: http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/Android_library

Please note that publishing the secret personal OpenCellID apiKey on the web is not recommended. Therefore I have deleted it now.